# FolderClosedIOException while reading mail with Java mail client

Tags: jakarta-mail

This is happening for some of the emails which have attachments > 2MB.

The stack trace I am getting is this:

```
com.sun.mail.util.FolderClosedIOException
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.forceCheckExpunged(IMAPInputStream.java:107)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.fill(IMAPInputStream.java:158)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.read(IMAPInputStream.java:218)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.read(IMAPInputStream.java:244)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.writeTo(IMAPMessage.java:849)
```

I looked at the IMAPInputStream code to see why its doing a expunged check, looks like its getting a `ProtocolException`.

```
    if (peek)
        b = p.peekBody(seqnum, section, pos, cnt, readbuf);
    else
        b = p.fetchBody(seqnum, section, pos, cnt, readbuf);
    } catch (ProtocolException pex) {
         forceCheckExpunged();
         throw new IOException(pex.getMessage());
    }
```

Anyone has faced this before? I am using javax.mail-1.5.6

Comment: Possibly the server is dropping the connection because it's been idle for too long.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: I am getting the exact same exception for certain email messages and they never seem to download when that exception first occurs. Doubt it's the server dropping the connection as it happens with Office 365 and keeps happening after the first instance.

Comment: Yes its Office 365 for me as well. I can't enable debug output as its happening on production.

Comment: Do you have found a solution for this problem?

Comment: no, could not debug it further

Comment: @SunnyAgarwal any help on this